# Response for JSONp request to youtube oembed call giving "invalid label" error

Tags: jquery, jsonp, oembed

I am making a JSONp call to youtube using oembed and on response firebug gives "invalid label" error

Here is my code

```
site = "www.youtube.com";
url = "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=slORb622ZI8";

$.getJSON("http://"+site+"/oembed?callback=?",{"format":"json","url":url},function(data){
    alert("hello:\n"+data);
    alert(data.provider_url);
});
```

Anyone ran into similar problem with oembed jsonp requests?

Comment: The url http://www.youtube.com/oembed?callback=jsonp1282594404887&_=1282594622137&format=json&url=http://www.youtube.com/watch%3Fv%3DslORb622ZI8 doesn't return JSON with padding, it just returns JSON.  Are you sure the oEmbed API supports JSONP?

Comment: i believe the problem is that, the youtube.com/oembed?.... returns only json and it doesnot include the part where a function should be called on jsonp return.

Is there a solution where the response is treated as text and not json? If i use dataType in jquery.ajax() to be xml or text, the request fails as ajax request cannot be made to an external domain

Answer (score 3):

### Problem

YouTube API doesn't support JSONP - see:

- [Issue 4329: oEmbed callback for JSONP](https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=4329).

### Solution

There is no need for a server-side proxy and no API keys are required.

Instead of:

```
var url = "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=slORb622ZI8";

$.getJSON("http://www.youtube.com/oembed?callback=?",
    {"format": "json", "url": url}, function (data) {
    alert("hello:\n"+data);
    alert(data.provider_url);
});
```

Try this, using the [Noembed](https://noembed.com/) service:

```
var url = "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=slORb622ZI8";

$.getJSON("https://noembed.com/embed?callback=?",
    {"format": "json", "url": url}, function (data) {
    alert("hello:\n" + data);
    alert(data.provider_url);
});
```

As a bonus this will also work with Vimeo links when you change `url` to:

```
var url = "https://vimeo.com/45196609";
```

and many other [supported sites](https://noembed.com/#supported-sites).

### Demo

See [**DEMO**](http://jsbin.com/hiwojowuge/edit?html,js,console,output) on JS Fiddle.

### See also

See also those questions:

- [Youtube Video title with API v3 without API key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30084140/youtube-video-title-with-api-v3-without-api-key/32190892#32190892)
- [Get Youtube information via JSON for single video (not feed) in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10066638/get-youtube-information-via-json-for-single-video-not-feed-in-javascript/32190378#32190378)

Answer (score 0):

Youtube’s Oembed API doesn’t currently wrap the JSON response in a callback. JSONP is simply not supported atm., and it seems like this won’t change anytime soon:
https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/youtube-api-gdata/5KuXxlLK07g

Here’s a ticket for a related feature request: https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=4329

The easiest solution would be to implement a small server side proxy to make the requests on the client’s behalf.