# Parse JSON info from Youtube - Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, youtube

I'm trying to pull in view counts for three different youTube videos. I've looked all over, and I can't seem to find what I'm doing wrong.

I followed this question: [Get Youtube information via JSON for single video (not feed) in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10066638/get-youtube-information-via-json-for-single-video-not-feed-in-javascript)

And using the script from there, I was able to get the viewCount for the video popping up in an alert, but I still am not exactly sure how to create a success handler that sends the viewCount information into a paragraph.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var video_id='VA770wpLX-Q';

$.getJSON('http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/'+video_id+'?v=2&alt=jsonc',function(data,status,xhr){
alert(data.data.viewCount);
});

});
```

Here's a fiddle of what I have so far: http://jsfiddle.net/wqwxg/199/

Comment: You mean like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/wqwxg/200/) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var video_id='VA770wpLX-Q';

    $.getJSON('http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/' + video_id + '?v=2&alt=jsonc', function(data, status, xhr) {
        $('#targetId').text(data.data.viewCount);
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<p id="targetId"></p>
```

Comment: Thanks so much! This is awesome. How would I go about adding in comments for every three digits? ie. 1,540,110 views.

Comment: Ask another question about that. In StackOverflow we solve one problem per question. Also, remember to mark this answer as accepted.