# How to test whether a YouTube video supports HD resolution?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

The YouTube API v3 allows you to [request information](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list) about a video, such as its title, description, etc.

Is there a way to determine whether the video supports HD resolution?

A [workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23253789/906814) could be to look for a `maxres` thumbnail:

```js
var checkURL = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?key=XYZ&part=snippet&fields=items(snippet(thumbnails))&id=" + uid;

$.getJSON(checkURL, function(data) {
  if (data.items.length > 0) {
    /* Verify this video is HD */
    if (data.items[0].snippet.thumbnails.maxres == undefined) {
      alert("This video does not support HD")
    }
  }
});
```

but is there a better approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check if a video supports HD by reading [`contentDetails.definition`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#contentDetails.definition) in a `video` resource:

> `string`
>
> Indicates whether the video is available in high definition (HD) or only in standard definition.
>
> Valid values for this property are: `hd`, `sd`