# Does using the YouTube Data Api generate any cost?

Tags: youtube, google-api, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I was wondering if the use of the YouTube Data API generate any costs (money which must be payed to Google).

I was only able to find the "unit-system" which is used by YouTube to limit the amount of requests?

Comment: Costs in what? money? data usage?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a programming question or any allowed question as defined in the Help Center.

Answer (score 22):

In addition to the answer by DaImTo I can add that if you don't need all of the YouTube API functionality (e.g. you only need to get video titles and thumbnails or something like that) then you don't need to be worried about the API restrictions at all, and you don't even need to use an API key.

I add this because a lot of people only need to get some basic data and get confused by all of the crazy API limits restrictions that keep changing all the time to make things worse, when you can get the same data without using the YouTube API directly.

You can get [oEmbed](http://oembed.com/) data from YouTube:

http://www.youtube.com/oembed?url=https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ

Or you can access it via [Noembed](https://noembed.com/):

https://noembed.com/embed?url=https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ

which (unlike YouTube) also supports [JSONP](http://json-p.org/):

https://noembed.com/embed?callback=example&url=https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ

so that you can use it on the client-side with no need for server-side proxies.

See also those answers for more info:

- [Youtube Video title with API v3 without API key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30084140/youtube-video-title-with-api-v3-without-api-key/32190892#32190892)
- [Get Youtube information via JSON for single video (not feed) in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10066638/get-youtube-information-via-json-for-single-video-not-feed-in-javascript/32190378#32190378)
- [Response for JSONp request to youtube oembed call giving "invalid label" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3551286/response-for-jsonp-request-to-youtube-oembed-call-giving-invalid-label-error/32190042#32190042)

Comment: Any way to get YouTube subscriber count using the ChannelID?

Comment: to oembed you need to have the id references, which you get when you use API video searches, this is usual hence the API need.

Comment: Can I get the video publish time with the video URL?

Answer (score 17):

> The YouTube Data API uses a quota to ensure that developers use the service as intended and do not create applications that unfairly reduce service quality or limit access for others. All API requests, including invalid requests, incur at least a one-point quota cost.

The cost they are referring to is the cost against your quota.

- 1,000,000 read operations that each retrieve two resource parts.
- 50,000 write operations and 450,000 additional read operations that each retrieve two resource parts.
- 2000 video uploads, 7000 write operations, and 200,000 read operations that each retrieve three resource parts.

There are a limited number of requests you are allowed to make against the API each day.  This is free for you to use it does not cost you any `money` to use this.   Some of the Google APIs may allow you to extend this quota but will charge you for the extension but this depends upon the API.

Info from the [Youtube API Quota documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started#quota)

Comment: Could you please give me the link to the price of extension quota? I searched on Google but there is no luck. Cannot find how much I must to pay for the extension.

Comment: Are you sure you have to pay?

Comment: I didn't find any document about this. I just want to know about the extension quota clearly.

Comment: Just try to extend it.  If it requires payment it will ask you to approve it first.   I seriously don't think you need to though

Comment: What is cost to extend the quota?

Comment: @Saggy to my knowledge there is no monetary fee to extend the YouTube Data API quota.

Comment: @DalmTo I want to develop personal app using YouTube api, does they allow it?I try to extend quota, they ask for your company information, and lot of similary questions.

Comment: @DalmTo besides asking for company information, they also want you to set up a payment method before you're able to make the extension request - can't assure that that means that you need to pay. But something to keep in mind.

Comment: If there is a monetary cost they will tell you and it would be documented.    They can't charge you for something without first giving you an idea of cost.   I have never heard of YouTube API costing anything to use.

Comment: What about my app is downloaded 100,000 times and used by say, 100,000 people. Will the restrictions be the same? 1,000,000 reads quota will be giving 10 reads or whatever to each user then?

Comment: Its a project based quota so you should probably consider requesting an extension

Answer (score 1):

They reason why here is YouTube quota:

> The YouTube Data API uses a quota to ensure that developers use the
> service as intended and do not create applications that unfairly
> reduce service quality or limit access for others.

### [Quota usage](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started#quota)

- YouTube Data API have a default quota allocation of 10,000 units per day.
- You can see your quota usage on the [Quotas](https://console.developers.google.com/iam-admin/quotas) page in the API Console.
- If you need to extend quota limit you can request it [here](https://support.google.com/youtube/contact/yt_api_form).
- You can find the quota available to your application in the [API Console](https://console.developers.google.com/).
- YouTube Data API (v3) - [Quota Calculator](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/determine_quota_cost)