# Youtube Video title with API v3 without API key?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Is it possible to get the video title using the video ID with API v3 **without** the API key? I could not find any information or example of getting the title in the API documentation.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

To get the video title, you *will* need an API key, and you'll need to make a request to:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet&id={COMMA_DELIMITED_LIST_OF_IDS}&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

In the returned packet, the title will be at `items.snippet.title`

You can't retrieve *any* API data without an API key; all API requests are on a quota system, and the key is used to determine how much to charge your app's daily limit. A call like the above, however, is quite inexpensive; it's a total of 3 units (2 for the snippet and 1 for the request itself). Since you get 50,000,000 units a day and can retrieve up to 50 snippets for that same 3 units, it's not much of a burden to use the API key.

Comment: Great, the video length field is gone from API v3. Why they have to break stuff that worked perfectly these Google guys?  >:(

Comment: It's not gone, it's just in a different "part" -- primarily  so that people who don't need the duration don't get charged for the quota (V3 is much more modular, whereas V2 just returned huge XML files to everything and ended up being pretty wasteful). The video duration is in the contentDetails part, so a request like this: https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=contentDetails&id={VIDEO_ID}&key={YOUR_API_KEY} will allow you to access the items.contentDetails.duration parameter. Note that the value is in ISO-8601-Duration format, so you might need to convert it.

Comment: This answer is outdated, see this https://stackoverflow.com/a/48884290/5304495

Answer (score 52):

## No need for API key

To get the video title, you will **NOT** need an API key, and you'll need to make a request to:

https://noembed.com/embed?url=https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ

Change the YouTube URL for the video that you need.

It also works with Vimeo and many other [supported sites](https://noembed.com/#supported-sites) with URLs like:

https://noembed.com/embed?url=https://vimeo.com/45196609

### Details

It is not possible to get the video title using the video ID with API v3 without the API key if you use the API directly. The YouTube Data API v2 is deprecated (see: [YouTube Data API v2 Deprecation: Frequently Asked Questions](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/deprecation_faq)) and currently the YouTube API doesn't support [oEmbed](http://oembed.com/) with [JSONP](http://json-p.org/) as it should (see [Issue 4329: oEmbed callback for JSONP](https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=4329)).

But fortunately there is the [Noembed](https://noembed.com/) service that lets you get the titles (and other data) of YouTube videos with JSONP and without the API key.

### Demo

Here is a simple demo to get the title with jQuery:

```
var id = 'dQw4w9WgXcQ';
var url = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=' + id;

$.getJSON('https://noembed.com/embed',
    {format: 'json', url: url}, function (data) {
    alert(data.title);
});
```

See [**DEMO**](http://jsbin.com/cufedixoju/edit?html,js,console,output) on JS Bin.

See also these questions:

- [Get Youtube information via JSON for single video (not feed) in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10066638/get-youtube-information-via-json-for-single-video-not-feed-in-javascript/32190378#32190378)
- [Response for JSONp request to youtube oembed call giving "invalid label" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3551286/response-for-jsonp-request-to-youtube-oembed-call-giving-invalid-label-error/32190042#32190042)

Comment: This is working awesome. Is there a way to perform search also?

Answer (score 28):

This is precisely the meaning of the **oEmbed** protocol.

> oEmbed is a format for allowing an embedded representation of a URL on
>   third party sites. The simple API allows a website to display embedded
>   content (such as photos or videos) when a user posts a link to that
>   resource, without having to parse the resource directly.
>
> This document is stored on [GitHub](https://github.com/iamcal/oembed).

More informations on the format at: https://oembed.com

```
https://www.youtube.com/oembed?url=http%3A//youtube.com/watch%3Fv%3DM3r2XDceM6A&format=json
```

Sample output:

```
{
    "version": "1.0",
    "type": "video",
    "provider_name": "YouTube",
    "provider_url": "http://youtube.com/",
    "width": 425,
    "height": 344,
    "title": "Amazing Nintendo Facts",
    "author_name": "ZackScott",
    "author_url": "http://www.youtube.com/user/ZackScott",
    "html":
        "<object width=\"425\" height=\"344\">
            <param name=\"movie\" value=\"http://www.youtube.com/v/M3r2XDceM6A&fs=1\"></param>
            <param name=\"allowFullScreen\" value=\"true\"></param>
            <param name=\"allowscriptaccess\" value=\"always\"></param>
            <embed src=\"http://www.youtube.com/v/M3r2XDceM6A&fs=1\"
                type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\" width=\"425\" height=\"344\"
                allowscriptaccess=\"always\" allowfullscreen=\"true\"></embed>
        </object>",
}
```

Here is a list of content providers that declared adhere to the format:

```
    "provider_name": "23HQ",
    "provider_name": "Adways",
    "provider_name": "Alpha App Net",
    "provider_name": "amCharts Live Editor",
    "provider_name": "Animatron",
    "provider_name": "Animoto",
    "provider_name": "Audiomack",
    "provider_name": "AudioSnaps",
    "provider_name": "Blackfire.io",
    "provider_name": "Box Office Buz",
    "provider_name": "Buttondown",
    "provider_name": "Cacoo",
    "provider_name": "Carbon Health",
    "provider_name": "CatBoat",
    "provider_name": "ChartBlocks",
    "provider_name": "chirbit.com",
    "provider_name": "CircuitLab",
    "provider_name": "Clipland",
    "provider_name": "Clyp",
    "provider_name": "Codepen",
    "provider_name": "Codepoints",
    "provider_name": "CodeSandbox",
    "provider_name": "CollegeHumor",
    "provider_name": "Commaful",
    "provider_name": "Coub",
    "provider_name": "Crowd Ranking",
    "provider_name": "Cyrano Systems",
    "provider_name": "Daily Mile",
    "provider_name": "Dailymotion",
    "provider_name": "Deviantart.com",
    "provider_name": "Didacte",
    "provider_name": "Dipity",
    "provider_name": "DocDroid",
    "provider_name": "Docs",
    "provider_name": "Dotsub",
    "provider_name": "edocr",
    "provider_name": "eduMedia",
    "provider_name": "EgliseInfo",
    "provider_name": "Embed Articles",
    "provider_name": "Embedly",
    "provider_name": "Ethfiddle",
    "provider_name": "Eyrie",
    "provider_name": "Facebook (Video)",
    "provider_name": "Flat",
    "provider_name": "Flickr",
    "provider_name": "FOX SPORTS Australia",
    "provider_name": "FrameBuzz",
    "provider_name": "FunnyOrDie",
    "provider_name": "Geograph Britain and Ireland",
    "provider_name": "Geograph Channel Islands",
    "provider_name": "Geograph Germany",
    "provider_name": "Getty Images",
    "provider_name": "Gfycat",
    "provider_name": "GIPHY",
    "provider_name": "Gyazo",
    "provider_name": "HuffDuffer",
    "provider_name": "Hulu",
    "provider_name": "iFixit",
    "provider_name": "IFTTT",
    "provider_name": "Indaco",
    "provider_name": "Infogram",
    "provider_name": "Inoreader",
    "provider_name": "inphood",
    "provider_name": "Instagram",
    "provider_name": "iSnare Articles",
    "provider_name": "ivlismusic",
    "provider_name": "Kickstarter",
    "provider_name": "Kidoju",
    "provider_name": "Kit",
    "provider_name": "Kitchenbowl",
    "provider_name": "Knacki",
    "provider_name": "LearningApps.org",
    "provider_name": "Ludus",
    "provider_name": "MathEmbed",
    "provider_name": "me.me",
    "provider_name": "Meetup",
    "provider_name": "MixCloud",
    "provider_name": "Moby Picture",
    "provider_name": "Modelo",
    "provider_name": "myBeweeg",
    "provider_name": "nanoo.tv",
    "provider_name": "nfb.ca",
    "provider_name": "Odds.com.au",
    "provider_name": "Office Mix",
    "provider_name": "Official FM",
    "provider_name": "On Aol",
    "provider_name": "Ora TV",
    "provider_name": "Orbitvu",
    "provider_name": "Oumy",
    "provider_name": "Pastery",
    "provider_name": "Pixdor",
    "provider_name": "Poll Daddy",
    "provider_name": "Port",
    "provider_name": "Portfolium",
    "provider_name": "Punters",
    "provider_name": "Quiz.biz",
    "provider_name": "Quizz.biz",
    "provider_name": "RapidEngage",
    "provider_name": "Reddit",
    "provider_name": "ReleaseWire",
    "provider_name": "RepubHub",
    "provider_name": "ReverbNation",
    "provider_name": "Roomshare",
    "provider_name": "Rumble",
    "provider_name": "Sapo Videos",
    "provider_name": "Screen9",
    "provider_name": "Screencast.com",
    "provider_name": "Screenr",
    "provider_name": "ScribbleMaps",
    "provider_name": "Scribd",
    "provider_name": "ShortNote",
    "provider_name": "Shoudio",
    "provider_name": "Show the Way, actionable location info",
    "provider_name": "Silk",
    "provider_name": "Simplecast",
    "provider_name": "Sizzle",
    "provider_name": "Sketchfab",
    "provider_name": "SlideShare",
    "provider_name": "SmugMug",
    "provider_name": "SocialExplorer",
    "provider_name": "Songlink",
    "provider_name": "SoundCloud",
    "provider_name": "Soundsgood",
    "provider_name": "SpeakerDeck",
    "provider_name": "Spotful",
    "provider_name": "Spreaker",
    "provider_name": "Streamable",
    "provider_name": "StreamOneCloud",
    "provider_name": "Sutori",
    "provider_name": "Sway",
    "provider_name": "Ted",
    "provider_name": "The New York Times",
    "provider_name": "They Said So",
    "provider_name": "TickCounter",
    "provider_name": "Toornament",
    "provider_name": "Topy",
    "provider_name": "Twitch",
    "provider_name": "Twitter",
    "provider_name": "Ubideo",
    "provider_name": "UOL",
    "provider_name": "Ustream",
    "provider_name": "Utposts",
    "provider_name": "Uttles",
    "provider_name": "VeeR VR",
    "provider_name": "Verse",
    "provider_name": "VEVO",
    "provider_name": "VideoJug",
    "provider_name": "Vidlit",
    "provider_name": "Vimeo",
    "provider_name": "Vlipsy",
    "provider_name": "wecandeo",
    "provider_name": "Wiredrive",
    "provider_name": "wizer.me",
    "provider_name": "Wootled",
    "provider_name": "WordPress.com",
    "provider_name": "Yes, I Know IT!",
    "provider_name": "YFrog",
    "provider_name": "YouTube",
    "provider_name": "ZProvider",
```

Note that this doesn't mean that **[CORS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing)** is enabled on this websites.

This datas are mostly made to be parsed server side.

Most of this information can also be obtained by parsing the `<meta og>` **open graph** html attributes of a given page.

See http://ogp.me/ for info about open graph.

Comment: This is a good answer, it doesn't need an api key and it doesn't depend on third party services.

Answer (score 3):

Yes You Can Without Any API Just **Requests** an **re** Modules

## Code In Python:

```
import requests,re

video_url = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2i2khp_npdE"

response = requests.get(video_url).text

title = re.findall(r'"title":"[^>]*",',response)[0].split(',')[0][9:-1]

print("\n[+] Video Title: {}".format(title))
```

## Output:

[+] Video Title: Alan Walker - Sing Me To Sleep

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible.

I made some rework of [excellent Porto's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52664178/911419), and wrote this snippet on Python:

```
import urllib, urllib.request, json

input = "C:\\urls.txt"
output = "C:\\tracks.csv"

urls=[line.strip() for line in open(input)]
for url in urls:
    ID = url.split('=')
    VideoID = ID[1]
    params = {"format": "json", "url": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=%s" % VideoID}
    url = "https://www.youtube.com/oembed"
    query_string = urllib.parse.urlencode(params)
    url = url + "?" + query_string
    with urllib.request.urlopen(url) as response:
        response_text = response.read()
        try:
            data = json.loads(response_text.decode())
        except ValueError as e:
            continue # skip faulty url
        if data is not None:
            author = data['author_name'].split(' - ')
            author = author[0].rstrip()
            f = open(output, "a", encoding='utf-8')
            print(author, ',', data['title'], sep="", file=f)
```

It picks a text file containing Youtube URL list:

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F_Vfgdfgg
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RndfgdfN8
...
```

and returns a CSV file with Artist-Title pairs:

```
Beyonce,Pretty hurts
Justin Timberlake,Cry me a river
```

P.S. filepath format in the snippet is intended for Windows, for Linux just use `~/tracks.csv`

Comment: Sorry, @Suncatcher, but what if certain titles contain commas?

Comment: just tried on title with comma and it goes fine. It shouldn't be a problem during writing the CSV, neither it shouldn't be a problem during parsing the generated CSV, you can wrap the title in quotes, like this `print(author, ",'", data['title'], "'", "sep="", file=f) ` or apply whatever rules you want