# Youtube video title and duration without api key

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

How can get the youtube video title and duration without using api key ?

I have checked [Youtube Video title with API v3 without API key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30084140/youtube-video-title-with-api-v3-without-api-key) link but this only give the title and not the duration.

So how can I get duration also without api key ?

Answer (score 3):

To people looking for an answer to this in 2020. You can do this using the [Youtube Iframe API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference). You don't need a API key!
First you insert the api link into the JS like so:

```
  var tag = document.createElement('script');
  tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
  var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
```

After that you create the player with the desired videoID like this:

```
  function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('player', {
      height: '390',
      width: '640',
      videoId: 'SIWbjgPYcJY',
      playerVars: {
        'autoplay': 0,
        'controls': 1
      },
      events: {
        'onReady': onPlayerReady
      }
    });

  }
```

Then you need to get the title and duration by assigning these in a variable to your HTML. We place this in the onPlayerReady.

```
  function onPlayerReady(event) {
    time = player.getDuration();
    $(".dur").val(time);
    title = player.getVideoData().title
    $(".title").val(title);
  }
```

Last thing is to put the player, duration and title in the HTML:

```
<div id="player"></div>
<br>
<span>Titel:</span><input class="title">
<br>
<span>duration:</span><input class="dur">
<br>
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ce53kmfb/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [youtube-dl](https://youtube-dl.org/):

```
$ youtube-dl -e "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2i2khp_npdE"
Alan Walker - Sing Me To Sleep
$ youtube-dl --get-duration "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2i2khp_npdE"
3:12
```

Alternatively:

```
$ curl -s "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2i2khp_npdE" | tr '<' '\n' | awk -F'"' '/name="title"/ { print $4 }'
Alan Walker - Sing Me To Sleep
$ curl -s "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2i2khp_npdE" | awk -F'"' '/itemprop="duration"/ { print $4 }'
PT3M12S
```

You can use this bash function to convert from the Youtube format to seconds:

```
duration_calculation ()
{
    local total_in_second=0
    local hours=0
    local minutes=0
    local seconds=0
    local duration="$1"
    
    if [[ $duration =~ ^PT([0-9]{1,})H([0-9]{1,})M([0-9]{1,})S$ ]]; then
        hours=$((hours + BASH_REMATCH[1]))
        minutes=$((minutes + BASH_REMATCH[2]))
        seconds=$((seconds + BASH_REMATCH[3]))
    # PT1H4M    H:M:00
    elif [[ $duration =~ ^PT([0-9]{1,})H([0-9]{1,})M$ ]];then
        hours=$((hours + BASH_REMATCH[1]))
        minutes=$((minutes + BASH_REMATCH[2]))
    # PT1H29S   H:00:S
    elif [[ $duration =~ ^PT([0-9]{1,})H([0-9]{1,})S$ ]]; then
        hours=$((hours + BASH_REMATCH[1]))
        seconds=$((seconds + BASH_REMATCH[2]))
    # PT4M29S   M:S
    elif [[ $duration =~ ^PT([0-9]{1,})M([0-9]{1,})S$ ]]; then
        minutes=$((minutes + BASH_REMATCH[1]))
        seconds=$((seconds + BASH_REMATCH[2]))
    # PT1H      H:00:00
    elif [[ $duration =~ ^PT([0-9]{1,})H$ ]]; then
        hours=$((hours + BASH_REMATCH[1]))
    # PT4M      00:M:00
    elif [[ $duration =~ ^PT([0-9]{1,})M$ ]]; then
        minutes=$((minutes + BASH_REMATCH[1]))
    # PT29S     S
    elif [[ $duration =~ ^PT([0-9]{1,})S$ ]]; then
        seconds=$((seconds + BASH_REMATCH[1]))
    fi
    total_in_seconds=$(( (hours * 3600) + (minutes * 60) + seconds ))
    echo "$total_in_seconds"
}
```

Comment: Thanks! what does ``awk -F'"' '/name="title"/ { print $4 }'`` do?