# How to get the duration of a video in iframe?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, iframe

I would like to know how can I get the duration (in seconds) of the youtube video that is in iframe. I really dont know if I should use PHP or JS, so I will welcome any advice. Heres is my iframe:

```
<iframe width='420' height='315' id='video_player' src='https://www.youtube.com/embed/0rVwuowU6Fs' frameborder='1' allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Thank you for any answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15596753/youtube-api-v3-how-to-get-video-durations

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Youtube API v3 , how to get video durations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15596753/youtube-api-v3-how-to-get-video-durations)

Comment: The iframe is https and cant access with javascript to this, then you must use google api only.

Comment: Good, thanks for your advices.

Comment: [youtube-video-title-and-duration-without-api-key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41295517/youtube-video-title-and-duration-without-api-key) [converting-youtube-data-api-v3-video-duration-format-to-seconds-in-javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22148885/converting-youtube-data-api-v3-video-duration-format-to-seconds-in-javascript-no)