# Get youtube video title without API key

Tags: javascript

I am able to get the title of a youtube video without using and api key using the jQuery code below, how can I use ES6 `fetch` to do the same?

```
const vidurl = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ';

$.getJSON('https://noembed.com/embed',
  {dataType: 'json', url: vidurl},  data => {
  console.log("JQUERY", data.title);
});
```

Comment: yes, that would be okay too, the example above is from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30084140/youtube-video-title-with-api-v3-without-api-key 

http://jsbin.com/cufedixoju/edit?html,js,console,output

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
const vidurl = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I_izvAbhExY';

fetch(`https://noembed.com/embed?dataType=json&url=${vidurl}`)
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(data => console.log('fetch', data.title))
```